# PDF images not showing up with lualatex/pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, luatex

I am trying to include an image in PDF format into my document as a figure. When compiling with `lualatex` or `pdflatex`, the image does not appear. If I take that very PDF image and convert it to PNG and include the PNG file, it works. Additionally, when I try the PDF version, the figure has a double light grey line along the edge or corner depending on the viewer used. This does not occur with the PNG version.

I have used the `\fbox` command to enclose the `\includegraphics` command to make sure that the size is being interpreted correctly and it is in all cases, and changing the image size doesn't change anything.

Generally, my compile order is `lualatex`->`bibtex`->`lualatex`->`lualatex` and I've tried the same thing with `pdflatex`. I have other PDF files that compile fine but this one has been problematic.

EDITED: Minimal Example

This preamble is pretty large but I figured I would include everything just to be safe. This is all part of a larger thesis template file for my university, so I can't really go deleting any of the packages either or it breaks the template.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[rm, tiny,center, compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{AT3-Iso.pdf}
    \caption{Three-dimensional traversing mechanism affixed to 7$^{\circ}$ cone model.}
    \label{fig:traverse}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also, I have linked 3 files below. One is sample output from my `.tex` file with a PDF input, one with a PNG input, and then one is the original PDF image itself that I am trying to use. Hopefully all of this helps.

http://people.tamu.edu/~sacraig/debug/pdf-version.pdf

http://people.tamu.edu/~sacraig/debug/png-version.pdf

http://people.tamu.edu/~sacraig/debug/AT3-Iso.pdf

EDIT 2: The PDF image is one page from what was originally a 4 page document split into 4 separate images. I tried converting each to EPS and then back to PDF again and it seemed to work for two of the 4 images.

Finally, I had been using MiKTeX when encountering this problem in Windows. I moved over to Ubuntu and on TeXLive it seems to all compile just fine. I still primarily use Windows at work, however, so I'd like to figure out the problem on the Windows side.

EDIT 3: Through additional testing I have found that `XeLaTeX` compiles fine and produced the proper output with this file in Windows. I can use that in a pinch, but I would still prefer `LuaLaTeX` if possible.

EDIT 4: Well checking the `.log` file showed one warning for the version of the PDF. It was 1.6 and I guess only up to 1.5 is supported. Resaving the PDF as PDF 1.5 fixed it for this image, so that is awesome. It doesn't seem to fix it for a couple other images that were created the same way, however, which is really weird. Those `.log` files don't seem to have any errors or warnings either.

Comment: It is too difficulty to decide what to do in this case since we don't have any info about the pdf file neither your preamble.

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  As Sigur said, it is very difficult for people to help you without seeing what you are (not) doing.  The problematic .pdf image would also be useful.

Comment: there may be something non-standard about the PDF file, try converting to something else (e.g. postscript) and then back to PDF

Comment: Including the pdf works perfectly with a minimal example and current pdflatex and lualatex. _And_ your example also works perfectly. And your file `pdf-version.pdf` is _not_ produced by `pdfTeX` or `lualatex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Martin: That's all well and good, except on my end it still doesn't work.

Comment: If that example file 'compiles' on windows but without the graphics showing up, do you see any errors or warnings?  You should go through the `.log` carefully and see if any further diagnostic information can be found.  Adding a `\listfiles` to the preamble will also help you track which versions you are loading.

Comment: The `.log` had one warning which, upon addressing it, fixed the issue for this image. I have other images that are still broken, however. Thanks a lot! I'll have to keep playing around with the others.